# Access chart in a user control from another user control

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, user-controls

So i'm inserting data on a chart in a user control in which the data is generated in another user control. i tried to make the chart public to be able to declare it.
everything seems fine and no error pops up!
but the chart still remains empty.
i would deeply appreciate your help
here's a little bit of the code:

```
public Chart signal_chart
    {
        get
        {
            return this.chart_signal;
        }
    }
```

and calling it in new user control:

```
Output_signal obj = new Output_signal();
for (int i = 0; i < time.Length; i++)
{
    obj.signal_chart.Series["Signal"].Points.AddXY(time[i], signal[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Output_signal obj = new Output_signal();
for (int i = 0; i < time.Length; i++)
{
    obj.signal_chart.Series["Signal"].Points.AddXY(time[i], signal[i]);
}
```

this code creates `Output_signal` instance, adds point but not actually displays `obj` anywhere. you need either use existing intance of Output_signal (which is a part of control), or add `obj` to `Controls` collection

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, it actually worked! :))